# Подобрать паттерны программирования

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем привет! Хочу попробовать реализовать паттерны программирования, преподаватель дал такие задания:

1. Есть магазин. В нём есть товары, заказы, корзина, пользователи.
2. В корзине может быть сколько угодно товаров, в заказе тоже. При чекауте корзина становится заказом.
3. В заказ и корзину нельзя положить товар, у которого кол-во ниже 0.
4. К корзине и заказу привязывается пользователь.
5. У заказа есть служба доставки
6. К заказу могут быть применены разные скидки: процентная, скидка на доставку, бесплатный товар (самый дешёвый в корзине)
7. При рендеринге страницы любой из сущности надо навешивать хуки вызова.

Нужно реализовать паттерны:

- Абстрактная фабрика
- Адаптер
- Инверсия зависимости
- Фабричный метод
- Наблюдатель

Не знаю с чего начать, думаю первое стоит определиться для какой задачи какой паттерн применить? Может кто-то их уже реализовывал и знает для какой задачи какой паттерн использовать?

Comment: Проанализируйте все паттерны. Начните реализовывать. Не думайте о паттернах в самом начале это не простая задача для начинающего. После того как сделаете реализацию не думая о паттернах попытайтесь разбить на классы и применить паттерны

Comment: Не бойтесь переписывать код это не страшная работа.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Прочитал книгу Head First - Паттерны программирования и вышел из тупика, там все максимально просто изложено.